# Show that these groups are not cyclic and hence have no such generator?

Tags: group-theory

I think that the groups $\mathbb{Z}^2, C_2\times C_4$ and $\langle(12)(34)(56),(145)(236)\rangle
$ are not cyclic and hence do not have such a generator, but not sure how to prove/show this?

Help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Insn't the group $\langle (12)(34)(56)(145)(236)\rangle$ given by a generator?

Comment: These groups are all finitely generated...

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ is generated by $1$. You can show $\Bbb Z^2$ is generated by $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$. Maybe you might want to re read what it means for a group to be generated by a set of elements?

Comment: Oh right, oops. @PeterTamaroff What does $\mathbb{Z}^2$ mean? I had assumed it was the set of square integers but is it actually the set (x,y)? And also, what is $C_2\times C_4$?

Comment: Is there a certain method to go about finding a generator?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the question is asking for you to prove that the groups are not generated by a **single** generator.

**Hint for ${\mathbb Z}^2$**

Assume by contradiction that the group is generated by a single element. Let this element be $(a,b)$. Then use the fact that $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are obtained from this generator to get a contradiction.

**Hint for $C_2\times C_4$** If $x$ is in this group then $x^4=e$ (Why?).. This proves that the group cannot be cyclic (why?).

**Hint for the last one**
$$[(12)(34)(56)][(145)(236)]=(135246)$$

Assume by contradiction that the group is cyclic, let $x$ be a generator. Then $x^n=(135246)$ for some $n$. What can the order of $x$ be? Once you figure the answer to that question, you are not done yet, but with some little extra work you should be able to get a contradiction....

Comment: Oh, I think I understand the first one...for the second, it if because $C_2\times C_4$ has length 8 but order 4, so can't be cyclic?

Comment: Yup. And if you need to justify it, you can easely use again contradiction....

Comment: Great thanks :) But if a group has length $n$ and order $n$ does that necessarily mean it's cyclic?

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Tamaroff writes, you seem to be a bit confused about what the word "generator" means. Perhaps what you mean is that none of these groups are generated by a *single* one of their elements (although with the last one, it's not clear what precisely you mean, so I'm not sure). A group generated by a single element is called a *cyclic* group.

On the other hand, every group has *some* set of generators --- for instance, the set of all elements of the group --- so I think people might find your title confusing.

(This should be a comment, but I don't have enough points for that yet.)